# Can I use std::vector.size() to control a loop that's removing elements?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a big headache in a object detector I'm working on.
I have already created this thread about other part that could be the problem: [Heap Corruption trying to add elements to existing std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049584/heap-corruption-trying-to-add-elements-to-existing-stdvector/29051065#29051065)

But, now, I'm thinking maybe the way I remove elements from a vector might be my problem. So, simple question, can i do something like this...

```
for (int i=0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    if(iNeedToRemoveThisElement){
        std::swap(vector[i],vector.back());
        vector.pop_back();
        i--;
    }
```

?

Comment: [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) should actually help to heal your _headaches_.

Comment: Yes you can, the loop condition been called in every iteration of the loop. But there are more efficient ways to do so. you can use `erase` to delete item from anywhere in the vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [This other `std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) might also help ;)

Comment: thanks people for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is OK (assuming `iNeedToRemoveThisElement` does not do anything bad, of course). The loop condition is executed every time, so you always compare with the current `vector.size()` reflecting the latest updates.

Also, a careful examination of the loop also reveals that you don't fall into the other potential pitfall of the comparison: If `i` is negative, the comparison would give `false` because `vector.size()` is unsigned. However it turns out that at the time of comparison, `i` is never negative.

There is one caveat where I'm not completely sure: If `i` refers to the last element, you swap that element with itself; I'm not sure whether that is defined behaviour (with the C++98/C++03 copy imlementation, there's of course no problem, but I'm not sure whether the C++11 move implementation also supports it). So it *might* be needed to special-case this. **Update:** As dyp explains in the comments, self-swap is allowed, so there's no need to special-case for it.

In any case, you should look up the algorithms `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` from the C++ standard library. They allow you to get rid of the loop completely, and if you can use C++11's lambda functions, it's also simpler than the loop.

Comment: The C++11 default move implementation of `swap` also uses a temporary, hence, self move-assignment does not occur. IIRC, self-swapping must be safe for various algorithms (see, e.g. [a comment by Howard Hinnant on that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455/what-does-the-standard-library-guarantee-about-self-move-assignment#comment17853023_13127916)).

Comment: @dyp: Thank you for that information. I actually suspected that it is required to work, but I couldn't find that information. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: As far as I know, this is yet another instance of "it's required to work because it's not allowed to fail". I couldn't find it in the Standard either, with a quick search.

Comment: @dyp actually the current standard says it's allowed to fail, see 17.6.4.9  [res.on.arguments]/1 (1.3) ... but that needs to be fixed (and I keep promising to write a paper about it).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry, I can't see in C++14 IS what you're talking about. I can see something about rvalue references, but how's that relevant for `swap`?

Comment: @dyp because the generic `swap` is defined in terms of move-assigning rvalues. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13129031/981959 and my answer there.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah silly me, I forgot about the first move assignment in my mental model. I wonder though if one can deduce the implementation from the requirements ("Exchanges values" in the generic version) In theory, two local variables could also be used as far as I can see, which would prevent self-move-assignment.

Comment: @dyp, yes, I suppose two tmp variables could be used, but noone does it that way, and users would complain about the extra move :) The standard should just be fixed instead.